# How do I "restart" a touch event in Android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom `View` and I'm overriding `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`. I've implemented pinch-zoom in this view as described in the article [Making Sense of Multitouch](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html). The issue I'm having is that this view is ultimately used in a `Gallery` which needs touch events for scrolling. I've added logic to detect when my view has fully scrolled to the right/left and return false, but I think the `Gallery` needs the full `MotionEvent` motion in order to scroll. Here's where I return false:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
    final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex( getActivePointerId() );
    final float x = event.getX( pointerIndex );
    final float y = event.getY( pointerIndex );

    // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
    if ( !getScaleDetector().isInProgress() ) {
        if ( isDetectMovementX() ) {
            final float dx = x - getLastTouchX();
            setPosX( getPosX() + dx );
        }

        if ( isDetectMovementY() ) {
            final float dy = y - getLastTouchY();
            setPosY( getPosY() + dy );
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    setLastTouchX( x );
    setLastTouchY( y );

    if ( isAtXBound() ) {
        return false;
    }

    break;
}
```

The `View` zooms and translates, but the `Gallery` never scrolls. I'm wondering if there's a way to basically resend the `MotionEvent` as a "fresh" `MotionEvent` with the initial action being `ACTION_DOWN`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MotionEvent`'s constructor to create a new one. See the article [Android: How to create a MotionEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867059/android-how-to-create-a-motionevent)

Also, the `obtain(...)` method creates a new `MotionEvent`. Try `MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain(event);`

See [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) for more about `obtain`.

Comment: If a `MotionEvent` is created, it is handled by your TouchListener.

Comment: Ah ha that's nice to know. I'm working with this to achieve what I want. I can already see it'll work, just need to do some tweaking. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem the the new `MotionEvent` is automatically signaled. In fact I never see that `MotionEvent` come through the onTouchEvent method.

Comment: That really surprises me. I just did some more looking around. I'm not sure this is the solution, but you could try using `dispatchTouchEvent`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: In fact, have you tried directly calling `onTouchEvent(event)` once you have made your copy of the `MotionEvent`?

Comment: That wouldn't work since I don't want it to go to "my" `onTouchEvent` in that case. From my observations `dispatchTouchEvent` also seems to just come back to my `onTouchEvent`. I'm seeing really odd behavior. I'm going to make a new question. Thanks for your help.