# Android edittext - enter in "text selection mode"

Tags: android, android-edittext, textselection

I have an EditText and I want programatically enter in "text selection mode" indicated by CursorControllers (handles), for example when user long press on EditText.

Any examples or suggestions will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
    editText.onTextContextMenuItem(android.R.id.startSelectingText);
```

for pre-Honeycomb versions and

```
    editText.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(/* FakeLongClick */));
```

for Honeycomb and newer.

I'm not familiar with motion events, but i think this should work if you are able to simulate a long click event...

Comment: Here's a helpful Q&A about creating MotionEvents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867059/android-how-to-create-a-motionevent

Answer (score -1):

you can paste some text to EditText by...

```
     <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_link"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Link" />
```

"Link" will apeear in EditText window

Comment: this is not an answer for my question.