# How to perform onTouch event from code?

Tags: android, events, touch-event

Using `myObject.performClick()` I can simulate click event from the code.

Does something like this exist for `onTouch` event? Can I mimic touch action from the Java code?

**EDIT**

This is my `onTouch` listener.

```
   myObject.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            // do something
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work, found here: [How to simulate a touch event in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android/7001356):

```
// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
// List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime, 
    eventTime, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

For more on obtaining a MotionEvent object, here is an excellent answer: [Android: How to create a MotionEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867059/android-how-to-create-a-motionevent)

EDIT: and to get the location of your view, for the `x` and `y` coordinates, use:

```
int[] coords = new int[2];
myView.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
int x = coords[0];
int y = coords[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to perform click motion event

```
View view;
view.setPressed(true);
view.setPressed(false);
```