# Get coordinates from USB 2.0 TouchScreen Monitor under ubuntu.

Tags: memory, usb, mapping, buffer, dma

I have a Touchscreen Panel working under Ubuntu and I need to find out where this device is writing the coordinates when touching the panel. 
Buffer? DMA REGISTER? USB REGISTER? Where can I get this information? How to get this information unter linux consol? How getting the physical memory location / buffer adress ?! ... 
Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general you can get the coordinates using the `evtest` tool, that reads input events i.e. in `/dev/input/event` see [How to get Coordinates of Touchscreen Rawdata using Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841139/how-to-get-coordinates-of-touchscreen-rawdata-using-linux) <- *very good answer*

Despite this other ways to get the data depend on your touchscreen (reading/writing /dev/ttySx ,...). Touch screens are in general implemented as USB HID devices or emulating a serial connection
(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen)

> **Checking for touchscreen connectivity**
>
> When encountering a new device, the first order of business is to
>   determine how the touchscreen is connected to your computer. If the
>   touchscreen produces no events out of the box, check to see if it's an
>   USB device or not:
>
> `lsusb`
>
> **USB connection**
>
> Check the output for any reference to a touchscreen. If your
>   touchscreen has an USB interface, and it isn't working, then you may
>   need to blacklist the usbtouchscreen driver for it to work:
>
> `sudo modprobe -r usbtouchscreen`
>
> If your touchscreen begins to produce events, then you can permanently
>   blacklist the usbtouchscreen driver:
>
> `echo "blacklist usbtouchscreen" | sudo tee -a
>   /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
>
> Some touchscreens might already have good or perfect calibrations,
>   otherwise you'll need to continue to the calibration section.
>
> **Serial connection**
>
> If there is no reference to a touchscreen device in your `lsusb` output,
>   the connection is most likely through one of your serial ports. The
>   actual IRQ mapping varies between manufacturers. In the case of
>   Itronix devices, the default is `/dev/ttyS3`. A simple way to check for
>   connections is to check each one for events:
>
> `screen /dev/ttyS0`
>
> Touch anywhere on your screen to check for any character output. If
>   nothing happens, quit screen by pressing `Ctrl+A` and then the `\` key
>   to quit. Continue with `/dev/ttyS1`, etc. until you get a response. Once
>   you've determined the device, we can try a few different drivers. In
>   the case of Itronix (and most other devices using the Touchkit
>   driver), the correct driver is `touchit213`.
>
> `sudo inputattach --touchit213 /dev/ttyS3`
>
> Will work for most touchkit screens. The calibration or one or more
>   axes may be swapped, but if the calibration is approximate then it's
>   probably the correct driver. Press `Ctrl+C` to try a new mode.
>   inputattach supports any of the following modes, which includes
>   external touchscreens which may attach through a physical serial port:
>
> - --h3600ts  -ipaq     Ipaq h3600 touchscreend
> - --elotouch -elo ELO touchscreen, 10-byte mode
> - --elo4002 -elo6b    ELO touchscreen, 6-byte mode
> - --elo271-140 -elo4b   ELO  touchscreen, 4-byte mode
> - --elo261-280 -elo3b    ELO Touchscreen, 3-byte mode
> - --mtouch -mtouch   MicroTouch (3M) touchscreen
> - --touchit213 -t213  Sahara Touch-iT213 Tablet PC
> - --touchright  -tr  Touchright serial touchscreen
> - --touchwin -tw       Touchwindow serial touchscreen
> - --penmount -pm       Penmount touchscreen
> - --fujitsu -fjt      Fujitsu serial touchscreen
>
> If your device is built into a laptop, you'll have the best luck with
>   the mtouch, touchright, touchwin, or touchit213 drivers. Likewise,
>   non-Elo external touchscreens will most likely use touchit213. If your
>   device is a tablet with stylus-only input, fujitsu is a popular maker
>   of embedded tablet devices.
>
> To attach the touchscreen at startup, edit your /etc/rc.local to look
>   like the following:
>
> `/usr/bin/inputattach --daemon --always -t213 /dev/ttyS3 exit 0`
>
> Replace `-t213` with your appropriate driver and `/dev/ttyS3` with the
>   correct device.
>
> Again, don't worry if the calibration isn't perfect, or if an axis is
>   inverted or reversed - this will be addressed in the calibration
>   section.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen