# How do I get input from my touchscreen with c++ while one linux.

Tags: c++, linux, touchscreen

I'm working on a c++/SFML paint program for my chromebook Acer R11 (running gallium linux) and would like to add multi-touch support. However I am stuck trying to find some way to get the input values into my c++ program.

The touchscreen works, full multi-touch works in chrome, non-touch applications treat it like a mouse.

SFML's sf::Touch methods don't give me anything, it appears they only work on android and ios.

I tried to get tslib to work, but it has zero setup instructions and I can't get the sample programs to compile and run.

I tried the c++ code in this thread [How to get Coordinates of Touchscreen Rawdata using Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841139/how-to-get-coordinates-of-touchscreen-rawdata-using-linux) but it stops at "You are not root! This may not work...\n", chrome gets touch events and its not root, so that's probably not the right direction.

**I haven't had any success finding info about this online. What is the proper way to get touch events on a linux system?**

More data:
The touchscreen shows up in evtest under /dev/input/event6: Elan Touchscreen
When I tell evtest to give me output it dumps realtime output correctly.

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices shows it as 
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=002a Version=0000
N: Name="Elan Touchscreen"
P: Phys=
s: Sysfs=/devices/platform/80622C1:00/i2c-0/i2c-ELAN0001:00/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6
B:PROP=2
B: EV=v
B: EKY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800001000003
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, when evtest really dumps everything correctly, you won't need [tslib](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib). In case you might need it anyways, there is more documentation now and I'd be happy to help you use it, when you create a Github issue there.

It seems more like a problem with correctly reading your system's input in your application though :)