# Android ListView animation material deisgn

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

in material design official guidelines I saw ListView animation - 
[Video link](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsQkFTSm13bUFLX00/components-progressactivity-behavior-Loading_Files_Circular_xhdpi_003.webm)

My question: is it some build-in animation or I should manually code it to achieve same effect. If I should code it, which tools/classes are used for this?

Comment: try this   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724964/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-they-appear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView is now replaced by RecyclerView for Lollipop per MaterialDesign.

This is a simple RecyclerView example with default MaterialDesign animations.

[RecyclerView Simple example](http://simplestandroidtutorial.blogspot.in)

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.