# how to apply animation to add item in gridview one by one

Tags: android, animation

I saw in one application that there was a `GridView` in which items were getting added one by one (not all at the same time).

I am looking for that animation.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: use this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: in `getVIew()` start any animation you want give some delay so that item will show after that much of time

Comment: @Mayank I am already following this link, but didnot get desired output, using this items are adding all together

Comment: @androicode :- I think Nilesh is right , if you want to add element one by one with animation then you have to implement code in getview of animation, which type animation do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the class LayoutAnimationController

Comment: Will you please tell me if we use setLayoutAnimation for controller then how could we stop this animation?

Comment: please add example code and source of code, this is not answer.

Answer (score 2):

getting hint from answer below my question about `LayoutAnimationController`, I am able to achieve the output as I wanted in my answer.

Below I am posting my code:

My animation class

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
    );
    animation.setDuration(500);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    LayoutAnimationController controller =
            new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
```

And I set it in my GridView as

```
gridView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RecyclerView` which can be found in [AppCompat Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview)

And then subclass [`RecyclerView.ItemAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html) and pass it as a parameter to `RecyclerView.setItemAnimator`

Some examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724964/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-they-appear) and [here](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators)

Note: to use `RecyclerView` as a grid, you need to use `RecyclerView.setLayoutManager` and pass [`GridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) as the argument.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add animation to your adapter in getview method like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
    {
         LayoutInflater inflator =  LayoutInflater.from(context);
         convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.grid_view, null);  
    }
    convertView.setAnimation(animation)
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The view is returning in the getView method of the adapter. So you have to add you animation to your view, here. Please see my code for you:

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);

        vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.iw = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iw);
        vh.container = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_label);
        vh.cateoryIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
        vh.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        vh.userScore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_picture_score);
        vh.progressbar = new ProgressBar(context);
        convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    UserHelper user = userList.get(position);
    vh.iw.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    vh.container.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(CategoryManager.INSTANCE.getCategoryById(user.getCategoryId()).getColorTransparent()));
    vh.cateoryIcon.setImageBitmap(CategoryManager.INSTANCE.getCategoryById(user.getCategoryId()).getSmallIcon());
    vh.username.setText(user.getNickName());
    vh.userScore.setText(user.getScore());

    Animation animation;
    if (position % 4 == 0) {
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.your_sexy_animation);
        animation.setDuration(340);
    } else {
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
        animation.setDuration(280);
    }

    convertView.startAnimation(animation);
    imageLoader.displayImage(user.getImageUrl(), vh.iw);

    return convertView;


}
```