# What is this component - Android

Tags: android, effects

I'm developing an Android application, and I want the effects of the Google music app, like that...

[image]

(The image of albums up with the list but more slow)

and

[image]

(The list of albums is in squares and this in from down)

I don't how to investigate what these effects are. Can someone tell me what it's called?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is a scroll parallax. Look into [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) or a [ParallaxScroll](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll) effect.

The second one is a layout animation added to RecyclerView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748274/1266326