# Animate RecyclerView onLoad

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, onload-event

I have been looking for a long time for a Android RecyclerView onLoad animation 
but until now I have not found anything really helpful.

What I want is to have an animation when the RecyclerView loads and displays the cells animated. 
But I want to have that animation just when the RecyclerView loads and not when the cells are loaded by the ViewHolder. 
Because when the cells are loaded by the ViewHolder the RecyclerView animates the cells while scrolling and so on... 
So I don't want no animation while scrolling anymore.

And some guys will know that the effect I would like to implement is 
a standard animation effect the TableView of iOS supports. 
I have found a [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/view-animation-in-swift/) where is exactly done what I would like to do. 
The last example is what I mean.

So all solutions I have found were similar to that [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724964/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-they-appear)

Has anyone an idea?
Or is the way I would like to animate the cells "not Android standard like"?

kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Well one way to do this is to make sure that you are animating the entire recyclerview when your activity / fragment is ready and displayed on screen. So instead of animating each individual item in the recyclerview, you set an animation on the recyclerview as a whole to "fly" in for example, by animating the TranslateY element of the recyclerview.