# RecyclerView: different ItemAnimators for different viewTypes

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecylerView` with different viewTypes and would like to apply different animations per viewType.

With `RecyclerView.setItemAnimator()` I can only apply an animator for all elements of the `RecyclerView`.

Is there a way to achieve different animations per viewType?

Answer (score 4):

Each `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` has method method that returns view type. Let's say if in your adapter, `getItemViewType(int position)` returns `VIEW_TYPE_HEADER`, the ViewHolder method `getItemViewType()` in any method you override in `ItemAnimator` will return this `VIEW_TYPE_HEADER`.

If you already doing this in your adapter, it is easy to distinguish the view type in your animator:

1. Create one common `ItemAnimator` that will wrap all different animators, set this animator to your `RecyclerView`
2. Do in methods like:

   ```
    @Override
    public boolean animateAppearance(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo){

    if(viewHolder.getItemViewType() == MyAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_ITEM){    
     //perform animation of usual item  
     mItemAnimator.animateAppearance(viewHolder, preLayoutInfo, postLayoutInfo);  
    }else if(viewHolder.getItemViewType() == MyAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HEADER){     
      //perform animation of the header
      mHeaderAnimator.animateAppearance(viewHolder, preLayoutInfo, postLayoutInfo);
    }else if(viewHolder.getItemViewType() == MyAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER){    
     //perform animation of the footer.
     mFooterAnimator.animateAppearance(viewHolder, preLayoutInfo, postLayoutInfo);
    }else return false;
     return true;

   }
   ```
3. Do the same with the rest of the methods you are going to override.

Comment: Thanks! How do you assign the `mItemAnimator` etc.? When I try `DefaultItemAnimator mItemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator()` and call then `mItemAnimator.animateChange(...)` my animations get mixed up somehow...

Answer (score 2):

You may add animation in *onBindViewHolder* method inside Your *RecyclerView.Adapter*. There You may check which element is going to be displayed (bound) and according to this knowledge set relevant animation and start it.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748274/4211194