# how to animate ItemDecorations in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

Is it possible to animate the ItemDecoration in a Recycler View as seen in https://youtu.be/imsr8NrIAMs?t=8m56s

I have been trying to figure out a way to animate the ItemDecoration with focus change.

Comment: check this link: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/07/implement-custom-itemdecoration-for.html

Comment: I have seen that link. It talks about adding ItemDecorations to RV but not actually animating them.

Comment: you can set animation in onBindViewHolder() in adapter. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26748274/4628611

Comment: I checked it out, but that does not seem to fix the problem. From my understanding the pink border in the video might not be an `ItemDecoration` at all since it is just not bound to every item