# How can I implement this scrolling effect inside recycler view?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, parallax

How can I implement this scrolling effect? As you see text is scrolling with delay. Can child view ignore or override scrolling by parent?

[image]

Comment: This is probably going to be needlessly difficult, as will be "pinning" the items to the top of the screen as shown.

Comment: hey Victoriia is this related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724964/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-they-appear  ?

Comment: @PedroAGSantos no, it's not exactly what I need, but thank you. I decided to animate each view on start scroll and stop scroll, but I don't want to call notifydatasetchanged() while scrolling as recyclerview starts flickering and scrolling position is lost.