# Odd behavior with RecyclerView animations using onPreDraw()

Tags: android

I successfully added onPreDraw animations to a RecyclerView using the following code. I call this function immediately after the adapter is set.

```
public void initialRVAnimation() {

    rvAnims =  new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    rv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    for (int i = 0; i < rv.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        View v = rv.getChildAt(i);
                        v.setTranslationY(Utils.getScreenHeight(LiveThreadActivity.this));
                        v.animate()
                                .setStartDelay(50 * i)
                                .translationY(0)
                                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(3.f))
                                .setDuration(700)
                                .start();
                    }

                    return true;
                }

    };

    rv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(rvAnims);
}
```

However, this causes an issue when adding items to the RecyclerView. The items seem to inherit the start delay specified in the animation and when a new item is added to the top of the RecyclerView, rather than all the items below moving down at once, they move in a staggered way. [Here's a video to demonstrate the problem.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SinLUcEKYSE) Here's the [normal animation when adding items](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQLWLnoj1cg) when not using the onPreDraw animation.

Items are added to the RecyclerView using the following code.

```
public void addItem(View v) {
    data.add(1, new Comment());
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(1);
}
```

Comment: use `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator`

Comment: Issue resolved using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909542/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-adapter-is-initialized-in-order/38937064#38937064