# Animation in the RecyclerViews

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement animation in my RecyclerView as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748274/8387050)

I have confusion to use this code as mentioned in post.

```
@Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)
    {
        ((CustomViewHolder)holder).clearAnimation();
    }
```

Its giving me error like this and I am not able to solve it

[image]

I have also confusion in add

```
public void clearAnimation()
    {
        mRootLayout.clearAnimation();
    }
```

How should I add and use it ?

Thanks

Comment: Use your ViewHolder instead of Parent class `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. That is, pass the name of the class type that you defined in your project that extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` as argument to the function `onViewDetached....()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Since method `onViewDetachedFromWindow()`expects as argument type a class which extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, Java will not let you override that function using a parent class.

**Solution:**

You need to use the same type as an argument as generic type you passed to your adapter. For example if your adapter class is defined as:

```
private class NewQouteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewQouteAdapter.ViewHolder>{ ...  }
```

You can use as type either `NewQouteAdapter.ViewHolder` or just `ViewHolder` to `onViewDetachedFromWindow()` function argument.

As for the second part, in the example you linked `clearAnimation()` is defined in ViewHolder class, and use `View` function on holder instance, wich is available through `itemView` variable, then called in AdapterClass on instance of `holder` object.

Or do not use your own clearAnimation() and just call View method in your adapter:
 `holder.itemView.clearAnimation();`

Answer (score 0):

How about  making your task easier and use a library already having that features?
I personally recommend try to give a look at those library`s :
1.  https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView
2.  https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5797
3.  https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

I`m using those library`s  and work as expected.

Update : As you don`t provide  more code to understand your exact situation i just can provide tips: 
  Try to cancel your animation  on [onViewDetachedFromWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

try to reverse animation on the same method :

```
    @Override
 public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
if (holder.getItemViewType() == poition) ((ItemView) 
  holder.itemView).reverseAllAnimations();
 }
```

Comment: I do not want change all codes just for this. I want use same as now. Thanks

Comment: Ok i tryed to give some tips  hope it helps you:)