# Correct way of implementing fade in/out animation for recyclerview

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I was wondering, what's the correct way of implementing fade in/out animation for recyclerview items (onClick event) using MVP pattern.

Well, my approach was following:

1. User touches item

[In my VIEW] 
`adapter.notifyItemChanged(position: Int)`

2. `onBindViewHolder()` reacts and this is where I set my animations:

   `override fun itemSelected(selected: Boolean) {
       if (selected) {
           notSoSpecialView.visibility = View.GONE
           specialView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.fadeIn())
           specialView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       } else {
           notSoSpecialView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
           specialView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.fadeOut()
           specialView.visibility = View.GONE
       }
   }`

Well, it works as I expect when Item is clicked - it fades out/in correctly, but, when I fastly scroll down/up, views get rebinded and now, every view calls `itemSelected(false)` which makes unnecessary animations. How can I avoid this?

I did try to use `specialView.clearAnimation()`, but that did not work.

Comment: Looks good, Have you tried notSoSpecialView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE?

Comment: You can try to use `setHasStableIds()` methods, specifying each item unique ID.

Comment: @AntonKazakov Can u give an example and explanation on why it should work? :)

Comment: only specific id item will be animated

Answer (score 2):

You need [ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html).

for example, you can refer this [link on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724964/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-they-appear) and also a very great resource from the [Medium](https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213)