# Animate all visible recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**I have already seen the questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724964/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-they-appear) but I want to translate the items of recyclerview at specific degrees**

I have tried [this](https://github.com/Lerist/CircleLayoutManager) library and item animation is required.

### I want below the animation.

[image]

So please suggest me how should I achieve item animation !

Here is the thing which I have tried till now

1. setup of recyclerview :

   ```
   final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
   final CircleLayoutManager circleLayoutManager = new CircleLayoutManager(this);
   final ScrollZoomLayoutManager scrollZoomLayoutManager = new ScrollZoomLayoutManager(this, Dp2px(10));

   SpacesItemDecoration spacesItemDecoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(
           (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._minus30sdp));
   recyclerView.addItemDecoration(spacesItemDecoration);
   recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);

   adapter = new Adapter();
   recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new CenterScrollListener());
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(circleLayoutManager);
   recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```
2. setup of layout manager :

   ```
   public class CircleLayoutManager extends RecyclerView.LayoutManager {

   private static int INTERVAL_ANGLE = 90;// The default interval angle between each items
   private static float DISTANCE_RATIO = 10f; // Finger swipe distance divide item rotate angle

   //Flags of scroll dirction
   private static int SCROLL_LEFT = 1;
   private static int SCROLL_RIGHT = 2;

   private Context context;

   // Size of each items
   private int mDecoratedChildWidth;
   private int mDecoratedChildHeight;

   //Property
   private int startLeft;
   private int startTop;
   private int mRadius;
   private int intervalAngle;
   private float offsetRotate; // The offset angle for each items which will change according to the scroll offset

   //the range of remove from parent
   private int minRemoveDegree;
   private int maxRemoveDegree;

   //initial position of content
   private int contentOffsetX = -1;
   private int contentOffsetY = -1;

   private int firstChildRotate = 0;

   //Sparse array for recording the attachment and rotate angle of each items
   private SparseBooleanArray itemAttached = new SparseBooleanArray();
   private SparseArray<Float> itemsRotate = new SparseArray<>();


   public CircleLayoutManager(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
       intervalAngle = INTERVAL_ANGLE;
       offsetRotate = 0;
       minRemoveDegree = -100;
       maxRemoveDegree = 100;
   }

   @Override
   public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
       if (getItemCount() == 0) {
           detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
           offsetRotate = 0;
           return;
       }

       //calculate the size of child
       if (getChildCount() == 0) {
           View scrap = recycler.getViewForPosition(0);
           addView(scrap);
           measureChildWithMargins(scrap, 0, 0);
           mDecoratedChildWidth = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(scrap);
           mDecoratedChildHeight = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(scrap);
           startLeft = contentOffsetX == -1 ? (getHorizontalSpace() - mDecoratedChildWidth) / 2 : contentOffsetX;
           startTop = contentOffsetY == -1 ? 0 : contentOffsetY;
           mRadius = mDecoratedChildHeight;
           detachAndScrapView(scrap, recycler);
       }

       //record the state of each items
       float rotate = firstChildRotate;
       for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
           itemsRotate.put(i, rotate);
           itemAttached.put(i, false);
           rotate += intervalAngle;
       }

       detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
       fixRotateOffset();
       layoutItems(recycler, state);
   }

   private void layoutItems(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
       layoutItems(recycler, state, SCROLL_RIGHT);
   }

   private void layoutItems(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler,
                            RecyclerView.State state, int oritention) {
       if (state.isPreLayout()) return;

       //remove the views which out of range
       for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
           View view = getChildAt(i);
           int position = getPosition(view);
           if (itemsRotate.get(position) - offsetRotate > maxRemoveDegree
                   || itemsRotate.get(position) - offsetRotate < minRemoveDegree) {
               itemAttached.put(position, false);
               removeAndRecycleView(view, recycler);
           }
       }

       //add the views which do not attached and in the range
       for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
           if (itemsRotate.get(i) - offsetRotate <= maxRemoveDegree
                   && itemsRotate.get(i) - offsetRotate >= minRemoveDegree) {
               if (!itemAttached.get(i)) {
                   View scrap = recycler.getViewForPosition(i);
                   measureChildWithMargins(scrap, 0, 0);
                   if (oritention == SCROLL_LEFT)
                       addView(scrap, 0);
                   else
                       addView(scrap);
                   float rotate = itemsRotate.get(i) - offsetRotate;
                   int left = calLeftPosition(rotate);
                   int top = calTopPosition(rotate);
                   scrap.setRotation(rotate);
                   layoutDecorated(scrap, startLeft + left, startTop + top,
                           startLeft + left + mDecoratedChildWidth, startTop + top + mDecoratedChildHeight);
                   itemAttached.put(i, true);
               }
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
       int willScroll = dx;

       float theta = dx / DISTANCE_RATIO; // the angle every item will rotate for each dx
       float targetRotate = offsetRotate + theta;

       //handle the boundary
       if (targetRotate < 0) {
           willScroll = (int) (-offsetRotate * DISTANCE_RATIO);
       } else if (targetRotate > getMaxOffsetDegree()) {
           willScroll = (int) ((getMaxOffsetDegree() - offsetRotate) * DISTANCE_RATIO);
       }
       theta = willScroll / DISTANCE_RATIO;

       offsetRotate += theta; //increase the offset rotate so when re-layout it can recycle the right views

       //re-calculate the rotate x,y of each items
       for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
           View view = getChildAt(i);
           float newRotate = view.getRotation() - theta;
           int offsetX = calLeftPosition(newRotate);
           int offsetY = calTopPosition(newRotate);
           layoutDecorated(view, startLeft + offsetX, startTop + offsetY,
                   startLeft + offsetX + mDecoratedChildWidth, startTop + offsetY + mDecoratedChildHeight);
           view.setRotation(newRotate);
       }

       //different direction child will overlap different way
       if (dx < 0)
           layoutItems(recycler, state, SCROLL_LEFT);
       else
           layoutItems(recycler, state, SCROLL_RIGHT);
       return willScroll;
   }

   /**
    * @param rotate the current rotate of view
    * @return the x of view
    */
   private int calLeftPosition(float rotate) {
       return (int) (mRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90 - rotate)));
   }

   /**
    * @param rotate the current rotate of view
    * @return the y of view
    */
   private int calTopPosition(float rotate) {
       return (int) (mRadius - mRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90 - rotate)));
   }

   private int getHorizontalSpace() {
       return getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
   }

   private int getVerticalSpace() {
       return getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop();
   }

   /**
    * fix the offset rotate angle in case item out of boundary
    **/
   private void fixRotateOffset() {
       if (offsetRotate < 0) {
           offsetRotate = 0;
       }
       if (offsetRotate > getMaxOffsetDegree()) {
           offsetRotate = getMaxOffsetDegree();
       }
   }

   /**
    * @return the max degrees according to current number of views and interval angle
    */
   private float getMaxOffsetDegree() {
       return (getItemCount() - 1) * intervalAngle;
   }

   private PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
       if (getChildCount() == 0) {
           return null;
       }
       final int firstChildPos = getPosition(getChildAt(0));
       final int direction = targetPosition < firstChildPos ? -1 : 1;
       return new PointF(direction, 0);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void scrollToPosition(int position) {
       if (position < 0 || position > getItemCount() - 1) return;
       float targetRotate = position * intervalAngle;
       if (targetRotate == offsetRotate) return;
       offsetRotate = targetRotate;
       fixRotateOffset();
       requestLayout();
   }

   @Override
   public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
       LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
           @Override
           public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
               return CircleLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
           }

          /* @Override
           protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
               return X / TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, Y, displayMetrics);
           }*/

       };
       smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
       startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
   }

   @Override
   public void onAdapterChanged(RecyclerView.Adapter oldAdapter, RecyclerView.Adapter newAdapter) {
       removeAllViews();
       offsetRotate = 0;
   }

   @Override
   public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
       return new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   }

   /**
    * @return Get the current positon of views
    */
   public int getCurrentPosition() {
       return Math.round(offsetRotate / intervalAngle);
   }

   /**
    * @return Get the dx should be scrolled to the center
    */
   public int getOffsetCenterView() {
       return (int) ((getCurrentPosition() * intervalAngle - offsetRotate) * DISTANCE_RATIO);
   }

   /**
    * @return Get the radius of the circle
    */
   public int getRadius() {
       return mRadius;
   }

   /**
    * @param mRadius the radius of the circle,default will be item's height
    */
   public void setRadius(int mRadius) {
       this.mRadius = mRadius;
   }

   /**
    * @return the interval angle between each items
    */
   public int getIntervalAngle() {
       return intervalAngle;
   }

   /**
    * Default angle is 30
    *
    * @param intervalAngle the interval angle between each items
    */
   public void setIntervalAngle(int intervalAngle) {
       this.intervalAngle = intervalAngle;
   }

   /**
    * Default is center in parent
    *
    * @return the content offset of x
    */
   public int getContentOffsetX() {
       return contentOffsetX;
   }

   /**
    * Default is center in parent
    *
    * @param contentOffsetX the content offset of x
    */
   public void setContentOffsetX(int contentOffsetX) {
       this.contentOffsetX = contentOffsetX;
   }

   /**
    * Default is top in parent
    *
    * @return the content offset of y
    */
   public int getContentOffsetY() {
       return contentOffsetY;
   }

   /**
    * Default is top in parent
    *
    * @param contentOffsetY the content offset of y
    */
   public void setContentOffsetY(int contentOffsetY) {
       this.contentOffsetY = contentOffsetY;
   }

   /**
    * Default is 0
    *
    * @return the rotate of first child
    */
   public int getFirstChildRotate() {
       return firstChildRotate;
   }

   /**
    * Default is 0
    *
    * @param firstChildRotate the rotate of first child
    */
   public void setFirstChildRotate(int firstChildRotate) {
       this.firstChildRotate = firstChildRotate;
   }

   /**
    * The rotate of child view in range[min,max] will be shown,default will be [-90,90]
    *
    * @param min min rotate that will be show
    * @param max max rotate that will be show
    */
   public void setDegreeRangeWillShow(int min, int max) {
       if (min > max) return;
       minRemoveDegree = min;
       maxRemoveDegree = max;
   }
   }
   ```
3. Here is result which I got till now

[image]

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: How do you expect people to help when you don't post any code?

Comment: @patrick-iv Okay I will update question.

Comment: @patrick-iv I have added my code on `https://codeshare.io/rujul`

Comment: post your code here, not on some random site

Comment: Okay sure Let me update question.

Comment: I used [LondonEye LayoutManager](https://github.com/danylovolokh/LondonEyeLayoutManager) library. They have done something similar if you scroll down on readme page. You will have to learn and modify it somehow. Idea is to move existing tile as if it is being removed from RecyclerView. Then, push new one in its place.

Comment: @rupinderjeet I have used `https://github.com/Lerist/CircleLayoutManager` library for achieving it. I guess now animation between items are missing.