# Android Recyclerview stop loading items which already loaded

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, lazy-loading

In my `RecyclcerView`, when I scroll down and scroll back up again, I want to stop binding the top items.

I tried this code

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(ItemTypeHead1, 0);
```

but position 0 gets rebinded again.
the reason I want to do this is rendering of each item is really heavy and that cause lag on scrolling.
 this is my adapater

```
public class HomeSliderListAdapter extends AdvanceRecycleViewAdapter<HomeSliderListAdapter.Holder, Banner> implements OnRecycleItemClick<Banner> {

public interface CallBack {
    void onClick(Banner Banner);
}

private Context context;
private CallBack callBack;

public HomeSliderListAdapter(Context context, CallBack callBack) {
    this.context = context;
    this.callBack = callBack;
}

@Override
public Holder createDataHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new Holder(makeView(parent, R.layout.row_home_one_banner));
}

@Override
public void onBindDataHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
    Banner banner = getItems().get(position);

    EpizodUtil.getPicasso(context)
            .load(EpizodUtil.getConvertedImagePath(banner.getImagePath() + "", Common.ImageSize.s10))
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .into(holder.img_background);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (callBack != null) {
                callBack.onClick(banner);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.txt_title.setText(EpizodUtil.checkNullString(banner.getTitleFa()));
    holder.txt_subtitle.setText(EpizodUtil.checkNullString(banner.getSubtitleFa()));
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to stop a `RecyclerView` to bind an item?

Comment: @rmanalo It has heavy content for each item and its caused lag on my app especially with old device

Comment: Then reduce the content of each items. You shouldn't display everything you want in an adapter. And optimize your images if you use some. Can you post the layout of your adapter?

Comment: @rmanalo of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't say to the recycler to stop to load the new items coming from the top.

In any case, the recycler view will call `onBindViewHolder` and it is in this function that you have to setup your item.

What you can do is to detect if the current item loaded (given by `onBindViewHolder`) is coming from the bottom or from the top.

Here an idea of what I mean :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private int mLowestPosition = -1;

    ...

    public CustomAdapter(...)
    {
         ...
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
         ...
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder iHolder, int iPosition)
    {

        if (iPosition > mLowestPosition)
        {
             // All item coming from the bottom for their first time will pass here.
             // Bind your view here

             mLowestPosition = iPosition;
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to reuse the data disappearing from bottom when you are scrolling up, you can get it by overriding `onViewRecycled`

Sources :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748274/5384689

[RecyclerView.Adapter.onViewRecycled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewRecycled(VH))