# Android: How to remove spaces between recyclerview items which appeared after setting scale to its items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've **RecyclerView** with **LinearLayoutManager** and horizontal orientation. I want to add it zoom in/out functions(like Trello Android app). I changed the items' scale:

```
itemView.scaleY = 0.7f
itemView.scaleX = 0.7f
```

Then space appeared between items. How to remove these spaces and place items one by one without space? [This is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yt1u.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to animate recyclerView items?

Comment: Yes, animate and shrink its items' width, height, text size, etc.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724964/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-they-appear

Comment: Judging by the image that you attached spaces appear due to the item decorator. Make sure you don’t add item decorators by this function addItemDecoration

Comment: I did not add any kind of item decorators. These spaces appeared after changing the item's scale.