# Fast scroll through RecyclerView breaks items placement

Tags: android

I'm the developer of [Fulguris Web Browser](https://github.com/Slion/Fulguris) and I'm faced with a weird issue in my tab list which is using a RecyclerView.

When scrolling fast through those tab lists, either horizontal or vertical ones, [items get stuck mid-flight](https://github.com/Slion/Fulguris/issues/139) as shown on below screenshot:

[image: Broken tab list]

That's hardly ever an issue when manually scrolling through the list. It mostly triggers when doing Ctrl+Tab which is using `smoothScrollToPosition` to move to the new current tab. It also seems to be more of an issue when under load like when loading web pages in the background.

Relevant source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Slion/Fulguris/tree/slions/app/src/main/java/acr/browser/lightning/browser/tabs).

Comment: Using scrollToPosition instead of smoothScrollToPosition fixes the issue. Looks like a nasty bug in smoothScrollToPosition implementation.

Comment: Actually I just tried again without item animator and with smooth scroll then it looks like the issue is gone too. It seems that's only a problem when using smooth scroll with item animator. That makes a lot more sense to me then. I wonder why I failed to see that earlier.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748274/3969362 and search for fast scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code base was using some custom `ItemAnimator` namely [`HorizontalItemAnimator`](https://github.com/Slion/Fulguris/blob/4a3b36d0b7d5970dc708517e6f34f7d508c1f035/app/src/main/java/acr/browser/lightning/list/HorizontalItemAnimator.java) and [`VerticalItemAnimator`](https://github.com/Slion/Fulguris/blob/4a3b36d0b7d5970dc708517e6f34f7d508c1f035/app/src/main/java/acr/browser/lightning/list/VerticalItemAnimator.java) that were causing those issues. My understanding is that those classes were once parts of the AOSP, looks like they are long gone though.

Using `DefaultItemAnimator` which is obviously set by default on AndroidX `RecyclerView` fixes those issues.