# How to set start offset for a (recyclerview) layout animation?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, document-layout-analysis

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54668740/6576302), one can set layout animation for recyclerview as follow:

```
res/anim/layout_animation.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:animation="@anim/item_animation_fall_down"
        android:animationOrder="normal"
        android:delay="15%" />
```

This works very well. But the fragment that My recyclerview live there has a slide windows transition from left to right and the recyclerview layout animation starts when that fragment transition is in its middle.

So I want to set a delay for recyclerview  layout animation to force it starts exactly after the end of fragment slide transition.

How to set start offset for a layout animation? (preferred solution)

I think this can be done by adding a listener to the fragment's windows animation, if so how?

This is my fragment transition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

and this is the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // data to populate the RecyclerView with
    ArrayList<String> animalNames = new ArrayList<>();
    animalNames.add("Horse");
    animalNames.add("Cow");
    animalNames.add("Camel");
    animalNames.add("Sheep");
    animalNames.add("Goat");

    // set up the RecyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvAnimals);
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, animalNames);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use handler for animation if you want to delay

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    // Start RecyclerView layout animation
    val controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation)
    recyclerView.layoutAnimation = controller
    recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation()
}, resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime).toLong())
```