# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.MotionEvent.setLocation(float, float)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I have a `DrawingView` class that extends the `View` class. In that `DrawingView` class I have a websocket client defined, where the client recieves a String and divides it into parts where each part will be inserted into an `MotionEvent` object. Then that object is sent via an `onTouchEvent` function in the same class and is handled later. So my problem is that the `recieved_event` is null when using it. Also if I define it locally instead of globally, Android Studio argues that the Object should be set as null. Is there any way to use the `recieved_event` without getting the null error?

```
public class DrawingView extends View{

    MotionEvent recieved_event;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
        super(context,attr);
        //the client socket is started
    }
    private final class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
        private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            webSocket.send("Hello!");
        }
        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            if(text.contains("!!!!")){
                String[] event_attrs = text.split("!!!!");
                //The recieved_event is null
                recieved_event.setLocation(Float.parseFloat(event_attrs[1]), Float.parseFloat(event_attrs[2]));
                recieved_event.setAction(Integer.parseInt(event_attrs[0]));
                onTouchEvent(recieved_event);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.MotionEvent.setLocation(float, float)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: I solved it by initing the object as described in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867059/android-how-to-create-a-motionevent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You must init an object before you start to use it, in this case, your trying to use `MotionEvent recieved_event` object with the method `.setLocation(float, float)` before init `recieved_event` object.

Comment: The only way is to init it as null,since `MotionEvent recieved_event = new MotionEvent()` will case the error `MotionEvent() is not public in android.view.MotionEvent. Cannot be accessed from outside package`