# How to filter out Long Press into a webvir

Tags: java, android-view, motionevent

I am embedding a youtube video in an iFrame using a WebView. I am trying to avoid sending right mouse clicks to the webview and it seems long pressing a webview sends the event to show the menu.[image: contextmenu]

I cant access the document of the iFrame from withing JavaScript, so I cant prevent right mouse clicks on the iFrame using JavaScript. Instead I am trying to prevent long presses from being sent to the webview. So have tried to override the webview's onTouch. It turns out the following doesn't pass the long click **nor does it pass any click**.

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
   return true;
}
```

or

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
   return false;
}
```

Adding `super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)` passes all clicks to the view. So I have tried to filter out long presses in the following way

```
private long startTime;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    } else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && System.nanoTime() - startTime < 19000000){
            super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Sadly this doesn't send click events if a user quickly lifts the finger after clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to do it using gestures. I created an onTouchListener for the webview and set it.

**How it works**

1. The listener runs a Gesture detector and returns true every time

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View webview, MotionEvent event) {
    detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
```

2. The gesture detector then filters out long clicks.

```
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float dx, float dy) {
    return true;
}
```

3. Since sending events onDown will trigger youtube to receive long presses so instead I [create down events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#obtain(long,%20long,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int)) only when I want to click or scroll like

```
webview.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
    event.getDownTime(),
    event.getEventTime(),
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
    event.getX(),
    event.getY(),
    0));
```

I had to actually have the down event created once on scroll by creating my own condition `boolean firstScroll`

4. Lastly I had to send an up event when all is done using the listener

```
class RemoteControl implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector detector;
    private boolean firstScroll = true;

    public RemoteControl(WebView webview) {
        Context context = webview.getContext();
        detector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
                webview.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
                    event.getDownTime(),
                    event.getEventTime(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    event.getX(),
                    event.getY(),
                    0));
                webview.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float dx, float dy) {
                if (firstScroll) {
                    webview.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
                        e1.getDownTime(),
                        e1.getEventTime(),
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        e1.getX(),
                        e1.getY(),
                        0));
                    firstScroll = false;
                    }
                webview.onTouchEvent(e2);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View webview, MotionEvent event) {
        webview.performClick();
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            webview.onTouchEvent(event);
            firstScroll = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Credit to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46618076/10285173)