# How can I trigger a swipe event in Android

Tags: android

I want to simulate a swipe event in Android app.[this link is for touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android)

Basically I want to slide to the next view when a user swipe on the screen or when he click a button, and the first one is trivial. The second one is complecated that I have to simulate or trigger a swipe event in the OnClickListener of the Button. How can I do that?

Comment: For swiping views you can try ViewPager.

Comment: @Anukool Yeah, I am using ViewPager. But how can I trigger a swipe event in code.

Comment: Are you using fragments ?

Comment: @Anukool No, I just use ViewPager and implement the onPageChangeListener. And now I want to be able to change pages when I click a button as well as use a swipe gesture.

Comment: You will have to implement OnGestureListener  and in the onFling method you can handle the swipe event.

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear. I mean that I have to generate a swipe gesture event programmatically. So I can change to another View by click the button instead of sliding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29716/discussion-between-anukool-and-zoujyjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already use ViewPager

```
 viewpager.setCurrentItem(i)
```

where i is a numer of page you want slide into

Comment: exactly! That is what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately I do get different behavior, when the user swipes manually and when I jump using setCurrentItem. The order of calls is reversed. When I swipe, it first calls OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected and then it calls setUserVisibleHint in the fragments. If I use setCurrentItem, it first calls setUserVisibleHint in the fragments and then it calls OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected, which really is a problem in my case :/ so I was hoping to find a way to keep the natural behavior but still programmtically move to another page.