# Is it possible to simulate a click on the screen in Android?

Tags: android, click, touchscreen

Is it possible to simulate a "click" (touch screen) by coordinates or on a view element?

Comment: what would this "simulation" produce?

Comment: For example:
If my app is a calculator I want "programming", you press "2" "+" "3" and "="
That is, simulate pressing on those 4 buttons. That is, the user will see without pressing anything like the "2" button is pressed alone, then the "+" ...

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to simulate touch events on android screen. If you have the coordinates of the view then you can generate touch events by using adb shell commands. For e.g-

adb shell input tap x y

where x and y are your coordinates. You can run this command from terminal. If you want to run the command from android code then use "/system/bin/ input tap x y" and run this by using Runtime.getRuntime() method. For details please reply, happy to help! :)

Answer (score 3):

As [azdev suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android/7001356#7001356), try this:

```
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            "View touched", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        );
        toast.show();

        return true;
    }
});


// Obtain MotionEvent object
long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
// List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
int metaState = 0;
MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
    downTime, 
    eventTime, 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 
    x, 
    y, 
    metaState
);

// Dispatch touch event to view
view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

Comment: Worked, very straightforward method to simulate onTouch over view/screen.

Comment: what is that float x and y? is it possible for targeting webview?

Comment: @gumuruh : Its x and y coordinates of the device screen to which you need to deploy touch.

Comment: if let say i obtain a location of x,y from a webview element....
and then i want to touch on x+20 and y+20 which means more to the right position and more to the bottom position... is that still touchable?

Comment: @gumuruh: It can be touchable but you have to add a check to confirm if it's not outside the screen. And btw, y+20 means more to the top position, not the bottom.

Comment: y+20 is to the top? I thought it was bottom? Because x,y are started  from corner left top screen right @BasimSherif?

Comment: @gumuruh Sorry, my bad. Yes you are correct

Comment: @gumuruh how can I click outside the app anywhere?

Comment: @gumuruh This method did not work to click outside the app.

Comment: if you want to click outside the app you need another framework @KaranSingla .... try google first android automation framework, you'll find several options available there...

Comment: I found a way. i achieved this by using GestureDescription.Builder

Answer (score 2):

presumably you have something that you wish to invoke via a click. So... if it's an actual button you can call `performClick()` on it. If it's not a button, then just call whatever the method you wish to execute is, when the conditions that you expect are met. It might help if you offered a little more details as to what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

On a View, yes.  By coordinates, a la Java Robot, not that I'm aware.

For example:

```
Button buttonFoo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_foo);
buttonFoo.performClick();
```

Comment: you can try robotium but it's very limited features.