# Performing click outside my app at a particular location

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to click at a particular location outside my app whenever "volume up" button is pressed.

So I thought of creating an android app whose service will indefinitely run in background. The service will be responsible for performing click on the screen whenever "volume up" button is pressed.

I need help with the code to perform click at a particular location on my screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reliably simulate touch events on Android without root (like Automate and Tasker)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775698/how-can-i-reliably-simulate-touch-events-on-android-without-root-like-automate)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a service for this. Just listen for the Volume Up button event. Look into this [Android How to listen for Volume Button events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162705/android-how-to-listen-for-volume-button-events)

Now About locating the points for clicking you can take help from this 
[How do android screen coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483345/how-do-android-screen-coordinates-work)

And for performing clicks [Is it possible to simulate a click on the screen in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647431/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-click-on-the-screen-in-android)