# Is it possible to simulate a tap on an android screen?

Tags: java, android

Im working on an app, which would contain arrays which will have their intervals and I want to run the array so every interval, the app would run in the background and simulate a tap on the screen

Basically, the question is, if I can simulate the tap, and if yes, how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reliably simulate touch events on Android without root (like Automate and Tasker)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775698/how-can-i-reliably-simulate-touch-events-on-android-without-root-like-automate)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this as part of an instrumented test, that is very simple:
(need to add UiAutomator for this)

```
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
device.click(X,Y)
```

If you want to click on the screen during a normal app run:
check [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16647580/2136812)