# How to use a virtual keyboard for flash game on android?

Tags: android, flash, sendkeys

I want to send keys to a flash game on android, as you know, when you touch screen, can control game but if you put some buttons over game, it doesnt work i mean, you cant control game. I think sendkeys doesnt work or I couldnt do that..

Is there any way to control game with external buttons on android?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate touch event in android. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android). It has been well discussed in StackFlow community. And good luck with it!

Comment: thank you very much, I will discover for it deeply :)