# How do you simulate a mouse click in an Android app using MotionEvent?

Tags: android, mouseevent

I'm creating an Android App for a TV platform with a webview, and I'm trying to provide a mouse mode where the user can move a cursor around with the DPAD.  Everything up to that works fine so far, but I cannot figure out how to click in the webview.  I'm trying to send a MotionEvent:

```
MotionEvent downEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, xPosition, yPosition, 0);
downEvent.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE);
mWebView.dispatchTouchEvent(downEvent);
```

But the webview seems to view it as a hover event and the link or whatever is just highlighted instead of clicked.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android)

Comment: this is happening to me as well even with the                         MotionEvent.ACTION_UP and the rest of the code from the above linked post. Did the code from the linked post work for you?