# How to programatically create a touch/tap on screen in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, touch

In desktop, We can simulate automatic mouse click with given coordinates. is this possible with Android? Can I simulate automatic touch/tap on scree.

Comment: this might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/q/4396059/5222007

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you can't.

You are welcome to write an `AccessibilityService`. However, this has only limited ability to manipulate other apps, and it requires users to not only install your app but agree to allow your app to have wide access to all their existing app's UIs.