# How can simulate touch event without root in android

Tags: android

Help me please.

I am making an app for simulating touch event like as automate.
I researched how automate works. but can't find anything.

I don't want to use adb because it need root.

Can I simulate touch event without root?
Thank you

Comment: Are the touch events for your app or for anything on the device? Please provide more detail. What are you trying to achieve with the touch events?

Comment: I want to control the other apps by simulating touch events in my app. Is it possible?

Comment: Controlling other apps like this is severely limited. It would be an extremely simple task to write dangerous malware if not.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples you could probably derive your own solution from:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android)

There are some answers <