# How to emulate touch by coordinates on keyboard (not view element) from android app without root?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to emulate touch and swipes on keyboard in my android app, I find a solution how to do it with dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent e) like in code here, but it doesn't work for me. What is wrong with it, or maybe there is better solution?

```
void simulateEventDown(Activity yourActivity, long x, long y) {
    MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            x, y, 0);
    yourActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
```

}
[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4evI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate a touch event in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android)

Comment: seems like no, because keyboard is not a view element from which we can call method, as i googled

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not just send the IME events?  I'd expect that to result in less flaky tests as keyboards change.

Comment: If you are about key codes, it's not what I'm looking for.  I need remote gesture (swipe) input