# How to create a custom view in android for swipe direction and positions in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a widget like this, kindly help me with how I can create it. Actually, I am creating an auto clicker and auto swiper app and I want to define the swipe direction and area using this widget.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found these two gitrepo for auto click. Catch the logic from these.
https://github.com/nestorm001/AutoClicker

https://github.com/Nain57/Smart-AutoClicker

Comment: already explored these links but did not help.

Comment: @YazdanIlyas you should learn about the gesture handling in android. Using that It can be done.
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures
and generating the touch

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).